# Не верная работа процедуры mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, database-cursor

Суть такая: В моем сервисе можно бронировать комнаты. Перед созданием новой брони, я должен проверить, не пересекаются ли даты новой брони с другими бронями на данную комнату. До настоящего момента у меня такая проверка осуществлялась через код java так:

```
List<Booking> bookings = bookingRepository.findBookingByRoomId(booking.getRoom().getId());
    Optional<Booking> roomIsBooked = bookings.stream()
            .filter(b -> (booking.getStartDate().after(b.getStartDate()) && booking.getStartDate().before(b.getEndDate())
                    || (booking.getEndDate().after(b.getStartDate()) && booking.getEndDate().before(b.getEndDate()))
                    || (b.getStartDate().after(booking.getStartDate()) && b.getStartDate().before(booking.getEndDate())))
                    || (b.getEndDate().after(booking.getStartDate()) && b.getEndDate().before(booking.getEndDate()))
                    || (b.getStartDate().getTime() == booking.getStartDate().getTime() || b.getStartDate().getTime() == booking.getEndDate().getTime())
                    || (b.getEndDate().getTime() == booking.getStartDate().getTime() || b.getEndDate().getTime() == booking.getEndDate().getTime()))
            .findFirst();
    if (roomIsBooked.isPresent()) {
        log.warn("In validateBooking incorrect booking dates.");
        throw new BookingException("Incorrect booking dates.");
    }
```

Т.Е. вначале я получал все брони на комнату и потом в стриме сверял даты новой брони со всеми датами других броней поочередно.
Теперь задача изменилась. Мне надо перенести весь данный код(с проверкой дат) в процедуру MYSQL.
С процедурами я еще не сталкивался, но вот что я придумал:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `validate_booking_date`(IN room_id INT, IN start_booking_date DATE, IN end_booking_date DATE)
BEGIN
    declare validate INT default 0;
    declare done INT default false;
    declare start_date date;
    declare end_date date;
    
    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT start_date, end_date FROM senla_traineeship.bookings b where b.room_id = room_id and b.delete_time IS NULL;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = true;
    
    open cur1;
    
    for_loop: loop
    fetch cur1 into start_date, end_date;
    if done then
        leave for_loop;
    end if;
    if (start_booking_date > start_date and start_booking_date < end_date) 
        OR (end_booking_date > start_date and end_booking_date < end_date)
        OR (start_date > start_booking_date and start_date < end_booking_date)
        OR (end_date > start_booking_date and end_date < end_booking_date)
        OR (start_date = start_booking_date OR start_date = end_booking_date)
        OR (end_date = start_booking_date OR end_date = end_booking_date)
    then
        set validate = 1;
    end if;
    
    end loop;
    close cur1;
    select validate;
END
```

Идея такая: если есть пересечения дат, то возвращать 1, если нет - 0. Но почему-то, моя процедура всегда возвращает 0. Не могу найти ошибку. Правильный ли я подход применил? Может быть что то можно сделать лучше? Буду рад любому совету.

P.S. Замечу, что данные условия такие же как и в java коде. В java проверки работают отлично.

Comment: Думаю проблема в это: ```set validate = 1;``` вы создаёте локальную переменную, сделайте так: ```validate = 1;```

Comment: К сожалению, validate = 1; подчеркивается красным.

Answer (score 0):

В итоге, процедура правильная. Ошибка была обнаружена в строке:

```
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT start_date, end_date FROM senla_traineeship.bookings b where b.room_id = room_id and b.delete_time IS NULL;
```

Произошла путаница из-за того, что перед start_date и end_date я не использовал новое имя таблицы b.